# How would I get the guid, knowing the name with xpath

Tags: xpath, aspdotnetstorefront

Given the following response, which may have multiple `Query` elements (that should have different names) and multiple `Row` elements, which should have different `name` and `manufacturerguid` elements inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AspDotNetStorefrontImportResult Version="7.1" DateTime="10/2/2013 4:17:04 PM">
 <Query Name="Manufacturers">
  <Row>
    <name>Nike</name>
    <manufacturerguid>84775261-731d-4e11-bb82-fa5f61bc61c5</manufacturerguid>
  </Row>
 </Query>
</AspDotNetStorefrontImportResult>
```

How could I use xpath to get the manufacturerguid, when I know the query name, and the name in the row? (tried the following to get the name )

```
//AspDotNetStorefrontImportResult/Query[@Name='Manufacturers']/Row/name[text()="name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath:

```
/AspDotNetStorefrontImportResult/Query[@Name='Manufacturers']/Row[name[.='Nike']]/manufacturerguid
```

The key is the `Row[name[.='Nike']]`, which finds the Row that contains the specified name element. From that row, you can then get the manufacturerguid.

You could also use the `following-sibling` to get from the name to the manufacturerguid:

```
/AspDotNetStorefrontImportResult/Query[@Name='Manufacturers']/Row/name[.='Nike']/following-sibling::manufacturerguid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `..` to gain access to the **parent node** (one level above).

```
//AspDotNetStorefrontImportResult/Query[@Name='Manufacturers']/Row/name[text()="Nike"]/../manufacturerguid
```

To get the `manufacturerguid` starting from the `name[text()="Nike"]` node, you can navigate to their parent using `..` (will take you to the related `Row`) and then go down again up to the `manufacturerguid` using `/manufacturerguid`.

#### Other options:

Another option is to include all the information you have in the `[]` query expression (`Query[@Name='Manufacturers' and Row/name[text()="Nike"]]`):

```
//AspDotNetStorefrontImportResult/Query[@Name='Manufacturers' and Row/name[text()="Nike"]]/Row/manufacturerguid
```

Or use multiple `[]` (works the same: `Query[@Name='Manufacturers'][Row/name[text()="Nike"]]`):

```
//AspDotNetStorefrontImportResult/Query[@Name='Manufacturers'][Row/name[text()="Nike"]]/Row/manufacturerguid
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different answer which worked for me.

```
/AspDotNetStorefrontImportResult/Query[@Name = 'Manufacturers']/Row[name = 'Nike']/manufacturerguid
```